# kendo datetimepicker in kendo grid value not coming to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, datetimepicker

I'm trying to pass datetime value from kendodate time picker in Grid. In my controller always I'm getting null value. How could resolve this?
Grid Column binding:

```
                    {
                        field: "ToDate",
                        title:"To Date",                        
                        editor: customDateEditor
                    },
```

Model Binding

```
ToDate: { type: "datetime"  }
```

Post data

```
let postData = {                                
                FinishDT:options.ToDate,    
               }
```

Custom datetime Editor

```
var customDateEditor = function (container, options) {
$('<input />')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDateTimePicker({
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved:
I have changed custom editor:

```
var customDateEditor = function (container, options) {
                $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" data-value-field="' + options.field + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" data-format="' + options.format + '"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDateTimePicker();
            };
```

Post data I have changed this way

```
FinishDT:kendo.toString(new Date(options.ToDate), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"),
```

and Field I have changed to type date

```
ToDate: { type: "date"  }
```